# Retrieve folders and subfolders to read a file in java using tail recursion

Tags: java, recursion, java-8, filesystems, tail-recursion

I am using normal recursion to a method to iterate and to get files from folders and subfolders in java.

Can someone help me in changing that to tail recursion method? I couldn't understand what tail recursion is. It will be useful for me to understand.

```
public void findFiles(String filePath) throws IOException {
    List<File> files = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))
                            .map(path -> path.toFile())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(File file: files) {
        if(file.isDirectory()){ 
                if(file.list().length == 0){
                        boolean isDeleted = file.delete();

                }else{
                    findFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
        }else{
            //process files
        }
    }
}
```

This is the normal recursion I have, can someone help me to write a tail recursion for this?

I tried a way, But I am not sure whether this is tail recursion and how it works.

```
public static void findFiles(String filePath) throws IOException{
    List<File> files = Files.list(Paths.get(filePath))
                            .map(path -> path.toFile())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(File file: files) {
        if(file.isDirectory() && file.list().length == 0){
             boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
        }else if(!file.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("Processing files!!!" +  file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A recursive function is **tail recursive** when recursive call is the last thing executed by the function.

Comment: @CommonMan - I googled and everyone told the same. In my case, reading files from directory and subdirectories, else is the correct place to call my function right? That's where I'm confused.

Comment: updated the post with what i tired. Could you please help me?

Comment: if `findFiles(file.getAbsolutePath())`  comes at the last of your loop then it is tail recursion but i see you using 2 else in loop, so it is not yet tail recursion.

Comment: Your `findFiles()` is not necessarily the last thing, it is inside a loop, so there might be other work done after it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tail recursion is a special kind of recursion which **does not do anything after the recursive call** but return.

Some programming languages take advantage of this by optimising the call stack, so that if you have a very deep recursion you don't end up with stack overflows (apart from the memory and invocation efficiency gains themselves).

The trick that is often used is that you add an extra *accumulator* parameter, which takes any outstanding data to be processed. Since this might make the recursive function less usable, it is usually done separately, so that to the user of your function it appears simple.

So in your example it would be like this, the normal `findFiles()` just prepares for the recursive call, while the `private` `findFilesRecursive()` is doing the tail recursive work.

```
public void findFiles(String filePath) throws IOException {
  //we use a Deque<> for Last In First Out ordering (to keep subfolders with their parent)
  Deque<Path> paths = new ArrayDeque<Path>();  
  paths.add(Paths.get(filePath);
  return findFilesRecursive(paths);  
}

private void findFilesRecursive(Deque<Path> pending) {
  if (pending.isEmpty()) {
    //base case, we are ready
    return;
  }

  Path path = pending.removeFirst();
  if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
    //todo: process the file

  } else {
      //it is a directory, queue its subfolders for processing
     List<Path> inside = Files.list(path).collect(Collectors.toList());
     if (inside.isEmpty() {
       Files.delete(path);
     } else {
       //we use LIFO so that subfolders get processed first
       inside.forEach(pending::addFirst);
     }
  }

  //tail recursion, we do nothing after we call it
  return findFilesRecursive(pending);  
}
```

Note that Java doesn't ([yet](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/272086/106466)) take advantage of tail recursion. Other programming languages like Scala and Kotlin do.

Side note, `Path` is generally more powerful from the old `File`, you don't need to change a `Path` to a `File` in your case.

Comment: I have to check file last modified time and delete that file. So, In that case i have to change a path to a file right?

Comment: Not really. Just do `Files.getLastModifiedTime(path)` and `Files.delete(path)`.

Comment: Great!! Thank for the help.

Comment: @Anjanaa select the answer if it is what you were looking for

Comment: Done. Thanks. This is what I am looking for

Comment: But since Java does not take advantage of the tail recursion, there’s no point in rewriting it this way—unless we also rewrite it to use a loop instead of recursion, which is now trivial. By the way, I’d use `ArrayDeque`, which consumes far less memory.

Comment: @Holger Yes, that's why I highlighted the fact that _some languages_ take advantage of this. (Although in the future the compiler might actually do that, like Scala and Kotlin already do). The OP specifically asked for tail recursion, so I presume the reason could have been simply an exercise to understand how to do it in this way. Re `ArrayDeque` yes it is a bit better from LinkedList because it doesn't allocate wrapper nodes, but it involves a lot of resizing and deep copying, and it is not efficient when removing from the front. So when using it as a stack it is not clear if it is better.

Comment: @jbx don’t confuse `ArrayDeque` with `ArrayList`. A specific difference is that `ArrayDeque` can remove from the front as fast as from the back (otherwise, it would be pointless to offer it as a `Deque`). Resizing does *not* involve deep copying, just copying an array of references and even with that potential resizing, it has “constant amortized time cost” for adding an element (at either end) and a net performance still better than `LinkedList` for most purposes.